# How to set autofocus inside Javascript Slider?

Tags: html, autofocus

So I basically set the following value:

```
<input class="enter-amount" name="amount" type="text" value="$" autofocus>
```

It works everywhere else but not inside the Javascript slider (wordpress Layer Slider), Im guessing perhaps JS is blocking it.. is there a way around it?